# tomcat 6.0.18 HTTPS not working

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

I am trying to configure tomcat for HTTPS on localhost.
I am using self signed certification.
I added folowing line of code to server.xml.

```
<Connector 
    port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLEngine="on" 
    keystoreFile="path-to-keystore" keystorePass="password" />
```

I am getting following error in browser:

```
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443.
Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
(Error code: ssl_error_internal_error_alert)
```

Can anybody guide me to proper direction. Thanks.

Comment: anything interesting in the server logs?

Comment: Is this the actual value you've given in the server.xml?

keystoreFile="path-to-keystore"

Comment: Thanks everybody for your reply, I think it was compatibility issue of Jdk and Tomcat. Same setting is working fine with Jdk1.5 and tomcat 6.0. But wasn't working previously with Jdk1.6 and Tomcat6.0.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the JDK.  We have a similar issue on one of our servers.  One has a self signed cert, the other has a "real" cert.  Both are running JDK 1.6.  The self signed cert throws this error.  The other does not.